# Android Studio: No attributes for components on preview page

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

There was an earlier bug that I fixed earlier, but now the attribute bar on the preview page is almost blank, whether the component is a textview, button, etc.  How should I fix it?

[Almost totally blank attribute bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64xIW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, here is a solution that worked for me.  You must first uninstall Android Studios, then delete all the files in C:/Users/xxx/.gradle and C:/Users/xxx/.AndroidStudiox.x .  Android Studio's uninstaller somehow leaves all that out.  Then reinstall it again.  It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you go and do that File -> Invalidate Caches and Restart.

Comment: <resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>